# Combining two tables with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Supose you have two tables with the exactly the same columns.

```
Table1:

Name   Type    AveSls
A       2       20
B       4       10
C       1       15

Table2:

Name   Type    AveSls
D       2       8
E       3       15
F       1       12
```

How do i combine the two tables in SQL server 2008 with a SQL satement so that the combined table looks like this:

```
Table3:

 Name    Type   AveSls
  A       2       20
  B       4       10
  C       1       15
  D       2       8
  E       3       15
  F       1       12
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use `UNION ALL` (to get all rows even if they repeat in both tables) or `UNION` to get non-repeating rows.

```
SELECT name, 
       type, 
       avesls 
FROM   table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT name, 
       type, 
       avesls 
FROM   table2
```

Read more about `UNION` on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [UNION](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) operator.
it's very simple to use:

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

See the following useful links:

1. [SQL UNION Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)
2. [Introduction and Example of UNION and UNION ALL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/15/sql-server-introduction-and-example-of-union-and-union-all/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```