# How to combine two different query into one table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 different query.Is it possible combine these query  ? If it is possible how can I do it ?

Query 1 :  http://pastebin.com/pAdP9Yub

```
      SELECT LatofTruck=Lat, LngofTruck=Lng, SpeedofTruck=Speed 

      FROM TruckLocation

      JOIN Truck AS Trucks ON Trucks.OID=TruckLocation.TruckID

      WHERE  TruckLocation.OID 

      IN (


      SELECT   MAX(TruckLocation_1.OID) AS OID
      FROM     TruckLocation AS TruckLocation_1
      JOIN     Truck ON TruckLocation_1.TruckID = Truck.OID  GROUP BY 
      TruckLocation_1.TruckID


      )

      ORDER BY TruckLocation.ReadTime DESC
```

Query 2 :http://pastebin.com/Esx36JHU

```
       SELECT a_TankLevel1,a_TankLevel2,d_AlertStation,StateOutAlarm,StateOutValve,

       SensorDataPackage.DeviceID,Branch.FirmName,LatofDealer=Branch.Lat,

       LngofDealer=Branch.Lng,Branch.City,Branch.FirmPhone,Branch.DealerAdmin  

       FROM SensorDataPackage

       JOIN Dealer AS Branch ON Branch.DeviceID=SensorDataPackage.DeviceID

       WHERE SensorDataPackage.OID

       IN (


       SELECT MAX (SensorDataPackage.OID)

       FROM SensorDataPackage

       WHERE  SensorDataPackage.readTime > DATEADD(DAY,-100,GETDATE())

       GROUP BY SensorDataPackage.DeviceID

       )

       ORDER BY SensorDataPackage.readTime DESC
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` could be used here - you have to make sure your column names(or aliases) are the same (and same number of columns too)

Comment: Post resulting table structure.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464167/combining-two-tables-with-sql/20464355#20464355

Comment: @MilenPavlov  There are not same columns in these two query

Comment: How you want to combine them? Merge datasets or join?

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski I want to merge.I have 2 google maps in one aspx page.Map get data from Serialization of one query.I want to be one map in one page by combine these query.

Comment: Based on what do you want to combine the results from these two queries? I see two different queries that have very little to do with each other...

Comment: @RonaldWildenberg yes they are different.Query is 1 for truck information,Query2 is for dealer information.I display on 2 maps.I want to be one map

Comment: @RonaldWildenberg   var markers = JSON.parse('<%=Dealers() %>'); var markers2 = JSON.parse('<%=Trucks() %>');  I display markers by result of JSON on maps.I want to be  var markers = JSON.parse('<%=DealersAndTrucks() %>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`UNION ALL`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) for this but you have to make sure you have the same number of columns and column types. So:

```
select a, b, c, from x
union all
select p, q, r, s, t from y
```

doesn't work but

```
select a, b, p, q, t from x
union all
select a, b, p, q, t from y
```

will work.

So in your case, you'd get something like this:

```
-- First query.
SELECT Latitude = Lat
     , Longitude = Lng
     , SpeedofTruck = Speed
     , a_TankLevel1 = null
     , a_TankLevel2 = null
     , d_AlertStation = null
     , StateOutAlarm = null
     , StateOutValve = null
     , DeviceID = null
     , FirmName = null
     , City = null
     , FirmPhone = null
     , DealerAdmin = null
FROM TruckLocation
JOIN Truck AS Trucks ON Trucks.OID=TruckLocation.TruckID
WHERE  TruckLocation.OID 
IN (
  SELECT   MAX(TruckLocation_1.OID) AS OID
  FROM     TruckLocation AS TruckLocation_1
  JOIN     Truck ON TruckLocation_1.TruckID = Truck.OID  GROUP BY 
  TruckLocation_1.TruckID
)

UNION ALL

-- Second query.
SELECT Latitude = Branch.Lat
     , Longitude = Branch.Lng
     , SpeedofTruck = null
     , a_TankLevel1
     , a_TankLevel2
     , d_AlertStation
     , StateOutAlarm
     , StateOutValve
     , SensorDataPackage.DeviceID
     , Branch.FirmName
     , Branch.City
     , Branch.FirmPhone
     , Branch.DealerAdmin  
   FROM SensorDataPackage
   JOIN Dealer AS Branch ON Branch.DeviceID=SensorDataPackage.DeviceID
   WHERE SensorDataPackage.OID
   IN (
     SELECT MAX (SensorDataPackage.OID)
     FROM SensorDataPackage
     WHERE  SensorDataPackage.readTime > DATEADD(DAY,-100,GETDATE())
     GROUP BY SensorDataPackage.DeviceID
   )
```

This will give you a result set that has latitude and longitude for both trucks and branches.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer.It does not display LatitudeofBranch = Branch.Lat,LongitudeofBranch = Branch.Lng.   It display LatitudeofTruck = Lat ,LongitudeofTruck = Lng in results.

Comment: Wildenberg How can I add and calculate new  2 columns in this query http://pastebin.com/hudXW4M1  (OldLat and OldLang of 5minutes ago ) Can you help me please ?

Comment: The idea is that you get *one* list of latitudes and longitudes that you can then use to show on your map. If you need separate column names for truck and branch coordinates, simply add two extra dummy columns to the first query and select the branch latitude and longitude from the second query.

Comment: I tried this but I failed.Can you give tips about this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517305/how-to-add-new-data-columns-of-old-time-in-sql-query

Comment: What have you tried? Why did it fail? What exactly failed? Concerning the other question: if you need the coordinates from 5 minutes ago, you must first store them in some way.

Comment: I tried this http://pastebin.com/jpFtztcg But newcolum(LatOf5mAgo) show for only one Truck.Result is here http://snag.gy/0BUqL.jpg

Comment: I want to show LatOf5MinutesAgo and LngOf5MinutesAgo for all Trucks

Comment: What you are trying to do is called a 'correlated subquery' but currently it's not correlated to anything. You have to add a where clause to select the correct truck in your subquery.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42960/discussion-between-mehmet-and-ronald-wildenberg)

Answer (score 0):

Hi [Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) would help you in such cases. If you have some common factor between both the tables, you can bring them into a same query and get data in to single query. I have used this feature several times. View is also a very good alternative solution for this.